# Transverse-plus, transverse minus, and longitudinal polarization of spin 1 particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory

What is difference in transverse-plus, transverse minus, and longitudinal polarization of spin 1 particle, and how are this related to its three spin projections states? What is difference in spin 1/2 case? If spin 1/2 particle has two projections of spin (i.e two transverse), why it is often longitudinal one introduced, and what is its meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing to note is that components of a field of arbitrary spin $j$ have nothing to do with space (e.g. there are not $2j + 1$ independent directions), so that your discussion of spin 1/2 just doesn't make any sense here. The reason we can interpret spin 1 field as vectors is that it transforms not only in the usual $SU(2)$ representation but also in the $SO(3)$ adjoint three-dimensional representation.

Now, since the vector has three components we can decompose it into arbitrary base of three vectors and it is obviously convenient to choose one vector in the longitudinal direction and the other two in the transverse direction. Since you explicitly ask, let me show you how this is done. Denote the longitudinal direction as the $z$-axis. Then (as always when dealing with spin) we can require that the basis of the representation be composed of eigenstates of the $L_z$ operator with eigenvalues $-1$, $0$ and $1$ so that the matrix $D_z$ is diagonal in this basis. Matrices $D_x$ and $D_y$ can be determined from the relation of $L_x$ and $L_y$ to ladder operators $L_{\pm} = L_x \pm i L_y$ acting on the $L_z$ eigenstates. This is the standard representation $\mathbf D$. Now, there is an unitarily equivalent adjoint representation of $SO(3)$ given by the matrices $M^i_{jk} = i \epsilon_{ijk}$. It is now a routine exercise to find a unitary matrix that transforms the representation $\mathbf D$ to the representation $\mathbf M$. Doing this is in reverse, this is also how you pass from the standard orthonormal $x,y,z$ components of the field to the basis of the $-1, 0, 1$ polarization states.

Comment: @Newman: I was talking about usual vectorial realization of the representation. This is in general not possible. For half-integer spin even tensorial representations aren't possible, there are just spinors. Spin 1 of course transforms in SU(2) representation, as does any other spin. On the other it has nothing to do with the Lorentz group since this group is non-compact and does not have *any* non-trivial unitary representations (that's why boosts are represented as non-hermitian matrices). Only the spin subgroup Spin(3) = SU(2) has these representations and it's here that spin comes from

Comment: @Marek, I think you have some misunderstanding here. Spin 1 particle is by definition a particle with wavefunction components transform under $SO(3)$. It has nothing to do with spin $1/2$ particle which is indeed associated with $Spin(3)=SU(2)$. The fact that you may map $SU(2)$ to $SO(3)$ allows us to operate with spin of spin-$1/2$ particle as a vector to some extent by constructing $\vec{s}=\psi^{+}\vec{\sigma}\psi$. But you should be really careful here because wavefunction transforms as a spinor and not as a vector contrary to spin-1 particle.

Comment: @Misha: I don't agree. Spin has *always* to do with Spin(3), not SO(3), except when people are lazy and forget to mention it. SO(3) only gives you orbital momentum, never spin. The reason one can pretend integer spins come from SO(3) (and exploit the nice tensorial structure thereof) is that we have canonical projection from Spin(3) to SO(3) which induces map of representations for integer spin reps. This map is used implicitly all over the physics and only people who are not careful or have no idea what's going on can claim that spin comes from SO(3).

Comment: Other way to say the same thing is that Spin group distinguishes bosons and fermions. Bosons have special property that they represent in a spinorial representation that is trivial on the kernel of the $\pi: Spin(3) \to SO(3)$ map and therefore bosons can be identified simply as representations of $\pi(Spin(3)) = SO(3)$. But it's important not to forget that Spin group is the fundamental one here (if nothing else, the name should ring a bell...).

Comment: And another remark is that your ubiquitous use of SU(2) is also due to accidental coincidence here. Again it's important to realize that spin doesn't come from SU(2). It comes from Spin(3) and one is implicitly using the isomorphism of these groups given by identification of quaternions with hermitian matrices. In general, Spin groups have nothing to with SU groups since they are just double covers of SO groups.

Comment: @Marek, when people say "spin-1 particle" it is usually shorthand for "wavefunction components transform under $D_1$ representation of rotation group". The origin of this $D_1$ may be different: it may be orbital momentum or some details of particle structure where parts with spin 1/2 are combined in a special way. But is you say "spin-1 particle", you no longer have SU(2). It seems that you are too concentrated on topology and miss some basics of representation theory. If you don't want to forget the origin of the spin, then it is better just not call this object "spin-1 particle".

Comment: Maybe it is better read $D_{1/2}$ instead of $SU(2)$ in my comment above.

Comment: @Misha: okay, it's possible that we have a misunderstanding here. One can also consider spin-one objects transforming under SO(3) (such as the wave-functions of spherically symmetrical problem). But this is a different spin than the one we use when dealing with elementary particles. Recall that their properties are ultimately deduced from the Poincaré group. After taking care of the mass, you move to the spin part using the standard Wigner small group. This small group is Spin(n) (i.e. SU(2) for n=3), not SO(n)!

Comment: By the way, I still don't understand why you can't accept that all particles come from a representation of just one group. Why would there be one group for bosons and another for fermions? It's crude, to say the least. Especially, when everything can be explained just from the point of Spin group... Or don't you agree that SU(2) has spin-1 representation? What else do you think its adjoint representation is?

Comment: Perhaps another piece of evidence might convince you. Weak SU(2) has a triplet of $B^{\pm}, Z$ particles that transform in its adjoint. This is weak isospin 1 representation. Of course, this is something else than what we've been talking but I just don't understand what your problem is with integer spin reps of SU(2)...

Comment: @Marek, indeed all representation originate from one group. But wavefunctions of different particles with different structure have different transformation law under actions of [transformations from] this group. Moreover, it is constructive to study these transformations laws also, and not only the group they originate from. It is how usually particles of spin 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2 and 2 are distinguished. Either this law is (I stick here to non-relativistic terminology for simplicity) $D_0$, $D_{1/2}$, $D_1$, etc. 
N.B. This $SU(2)$ here is really misleading.

Comment: @Misha: Of course they have different transformation laws. That's what being in a different representation (or having different spin) means by definition. My point was that you acknowledge that *all* particles come from SU(2) and that usage of SO(3) is secondary and can be deduced from the SU(2). The weak isospin example is a bit misleading but I am quickly becoming desperate by this discussion where we argue over completely trivial matters and can't seem to reach agreement...

Comment: @Marek, it seems that we have an agreement. The confusing part is this $SU(2)$ terminology which is too broad. For me all of them: $SU(2)$, $SO(3)$ and others are deduced from rotations of space (you may either say that it "is" SO(3) and SU(2) is universal cover or construct rotations as a projective space isomorph to SU(2) from the beginning). For you $SU(2)$ is "more fundamental". I can live with it.

Comment: @Misha: actually, rereading your very first comment, it is possible that I completely misunderstood you. You were just saying that vector interpretation is not possible for spin 1/2 particle, right? I am not sure why you posted that comment though, since I agree with this and I don't think I've argued with this statement anywhere in my answer.